# In Go, how to verify that the data type of an input from the user matches the data type of the code?

Tags: go, types

I am new to Go.

Currently, I am creating a menu in Go and I want to verify that the data type of the input from the user matches the data type of the variable defined in the code. Part of my code looks like this so far:

```golang
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

var option int // The variable is declared outside of the main().

func general_menu() {
    fmt.Println(".......................General Menu..................................")
        fmt.Println()
        fmt.Println("Calculator..........................................................1")
        fmt.Println("Linear algebra package..............................................2")
        fmt.Println("Language change.....................................................9")
        fmt.Println("Exit...............................................................10")
        fmt.Println()
        fmt.Println("Choose an option from the menu.")
        fmt.Println()
        fmt.Scan(&option)
        fmt.Println()
        if (option != 1 && option != 2 && option != 9 && option != 10)||reflect.TypeOf(option)!=int{
            fmt.Println("Wrong option input. Please, try again.")
            fmt.Println()
            general_menu()
        }
}
```

I know that this doens't work this way, and I know that "int" can not be used as part of an "if" condirion.

I would kindly appreciate any suggestions on the proper way to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Edit: I have added more of my code as kindly suggested by the contributors.

Edit: Based on the answer provided, I have tried to implement a function, but the syntax is still not correct:

```golang
func check_integers_are_not_string(x int) bool {
    change := strconv.Itoa(x)
    if change != nil {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
} // This function returns a true boolean value if conversion from int to string was possible, meaning that the entered value is a string.
```

Comment: Can you show the part wher e you're collecting input from the user?  Is it not coming from `stdin`?

Comment: You can use `fmt.Scanf`, it checks types and return error if doesn't matched

Comment: Can you clarify the question? Go is a statically-typed language, `option` has a type and will always be that type.

Comment: I am trying to generate an error message, while preventing the program from crashing, if the user does not input an integer number.
Thanks.

Comment: At the same time, I would like the user to retry if he/she types a character or a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just read the documentation of Scan - https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Scan

It returns the number of successfully read arguments and an error. The input is mapped in your case to a variable of type int, so if a user inputs a string it will return 0 and an error. Otherwise it will return 1 and the error should be nil. You can check for that.

```
n, err := fmt.Scan(&option)
if n != 1 || err != nil {
  // print error and go back 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One common way to do it is to try to make the conversion and see if it succeeds.

```golang
optionInt, err := strconv.Atoi(option) // Assuming option is of type string
if err != nil {
    log.Printf("String '%s' cannot be converted to type int: %v", option, err)
    os.Exit(1)
}
log.Printf(`optionInt is %d.`, optionInt)
```

This is a good approach if you are only interested in conversion to one type. Otherwise things can quickly get more involved, utilizing constructs such as lexers and parsers, but that would warrant more information on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!
In my case, "option" is of int type.
However, you have given me very good ideas to work and try.